# How to control stack size in Guava's AbstractLoadingCache?

Tags: java, caching, guava

It is said in [Guava's doc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/AbstractLoadingCache.html), that

> To implement a cache, the programmer needs only to extend this class
>   and provide an implementation for the LoadingCache.get(Object) and
>   Cache.getIfPresent(java.lang.Object) methods.

But how about cache size? Any cache is good when it is able to forget old data. How to control this?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `AbstractLoadingCache`, you're expected to be writing your own cache implementation and to control those details yourself.

If you just want a pre-built cache with things like limiting the maximum size, use `CacheBuilder` and use the `maximumSize` method.

Comment: It is said "programmer needs only to extend"... Not said I expected to do something else, neither said HOW to do if I want...

Comment: @SuzanCioc How could `AbstractLoadingCache` tell you how to do it when it's entirely up to you?  You could implement any kind of cache you wanted.

Comment: The point of `AbstractLoadingCache` is to be there if you want to write an entirely new cache implementation with a custom data structure.  It's up to you to build whatever that custom data structure needs -- size limits, custom caching behavior, whatever.  If you don't want to build your own caching data structure from scratch, that's what `CacheBuilder` is there for -- it's a fairly powerful, general-case cache implementation.

Comment: If I would build my stack structure from scratch, I would not use `AbstractLoadingCache` since it contains "no meat". I would use just `HashMap` or some other standard empty classes. So, may be I am wrong and just don't understand the purpose of this class?